# movement of rendered objects in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, coordinate-transformation

I'm having trouble moving these objects in an orderly fashion with openGL.

What I want to do is have each object in each row slowly spin and move the right of the screen, and as it disappears from view it should reappear on the other side as if in a loop.

The idle function worked fine for a single object, but it's not working with the group of objects.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

GLuint objectList;

GLfloat xRotated, yRotated, zRotated;
GLdouble size = 0.5;

float xpos = 0.0;
float ypos = 0.0;
float zpos = 0.0;

int x = 1;
float r, g, b;

/*
* Initialize depth buffer, projection matrix, light source, and lighting
* model.  Do not specify a material property here.
*/
void init(void)
{
    GLfloat ambient[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat diffuse[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat position[] = { 0.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0 };

    GLfloat lmodel_ambient[] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 };
    GLfloat local_view[] = { 0.0 };

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, lmodel_ambient);
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, local_view);

    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_AUTO_NORMAL);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


    objectList = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(objectList, GL_COMPILE);
    glutSolidTeapot(0.5);
    glEndList();
}

/*
* Move object into position.  Use 3rd through 12th
* parameters to specify the material property.  Draw a teapot.
*/
void renderObject(GLfloat x, GLfloat y,
    GLfloat ambr, GLfloat ambg, GLfloat ambb,
    GLfloat difr, GLfloat difg, GLfloat difb,
    GLfloat specr, GLfloat specg, GLfloat specb, GLfloat shine)
{
    GLfloat mat[4];

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0);
    mat[0] = ambr; mat[1] = ambg; mat[2] = ambb; mat[3] = 1.0;
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat);
    mat[0] = difr; mat[1] = difg; mat[2] = difb;
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat);
    mat[0] = specr; mat[1] = specg; mat[2] = specb;
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, shine * 128.0);
    glCallList(objectList);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void idle(void) {

    //xRotated += 0.01;
    yRotated += 0.01;
    //zRotated += 0.01;

    if (xpos > -1 && x == 1) {

        xpos = -15;
        ypos = 0;

    }
    else {
        x = 0;

        if (xpos <= 15) {
            xpos += 0.001;
            //ypos += 0.001;
        }
        else {
            xpos = 1;
            ypos = 1;
            x = 1;
        }
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}


void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // glRotatef(xRotated, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    // rotation about Y axis
    glRotatef(xRotated, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    // rotation about the Z axis
    glRotatef(yRotated, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    // scale transformation
    glScalef(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    // glut spheres

    renderObject(2.0, 11.0, 0.05375, 0.05, 0.06625,
        0.18275, 0.17, 0.22525, 0.332741, 0.328634, 0.346435, 0.3);
    renderObject(2.0, 8.0, 0.25, 0.20725, 0.20725,
        1, 0.829, 0.829, 0.296648, 0.296648, 0.296648, 0.088);
    renderObject(2.0, 5.0, 0.1745, 0.01175, 0.01175,
        0.61424, 0.04136, 0.04136, 0.727811, 0.626959, 0.626959, 0.6);

    renderObject(6.0, 11.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25,
        0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.774597, 0.774597, 0.774597, 0.6);
    renderObject(6.0, 8.0, 0.19125, 0.0735, 0.0225,
        0.7038, 0.27048, 0.0828, 0.256777, 0.137622, 0.086014, 0.1);
    renderObject(6.0, 5.0, 0.24725, 0.1995, 0.0745,
        0.75164, 0.60648, 0.22648, 0.628281, 0.555802, 0.366065, 0.4);


    renderObject(10.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.1, 0.35, 0.1, 0.45, 0.55, 0.45, .25);
    renderObject(10.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.7, 0.6, 0.6, .25);
    renderObject(10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55,
        0.70, 0.70, 0.70, .25);

    renderObject(14.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.0, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4,
        0.04, 0.7, 0.04, .078125);
    renderObject(14.0, 8.0, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4,
        0.7, 0.04, 0.04, .078125);
    renderObject(14.0, 5.0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, .078125);

    renderObject(18.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.0, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4,
        0.04, 0.7, 0.04, .078125);
    renderObject(18.0, 8.0, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4,
        0.7, 0.04, 0.04, .078125);
    renderObject(18.0, 5.0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, .078125);


    glutSwapBuffers();
}


void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho(0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 16.0*(GLfloat)h / (GLfloat)w,
            -10.0, 10.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}



/*
* Main Loop
*/
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(750, 750);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    init();
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That looks like C and probably even  compiles as such. `stdlib.h` in C++ is deprecated C-compatibility header - use `cstdlib` and the like instead, which also put things in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the order of the instructions. A rotation around the axis of the object is performed, by multiplying the translation matrix by the rotation matrix.

```
object-matrix = translation-matrix * rotation-matrix
```

[image]

See the documentation of [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) which clearly says:

> `glRotate` produces a rotation of angle degrees around the vector `x` `y` `z`. The current matrix (see `glMatrixMode`) is multiplied by a rotation matrix with the product replacing the current matrix.

Adapt your code like this:

```
void renderObject(GLfloat x, GLfloat y,
    GLfloat ambr, GLfloat ambg, GLfloat ambb,
    GLfloat difr, GLfloat difg, GLfloat difb,
    GLfloat specr, GLfloat specg, GLfloat specb, GLfloat shine)
{
    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0);            // translation-matrix
    glRotatef(yRotated, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // multiply by rotation-matrix
    glRotatef(xRotated, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    .....
}
```

Note, your rotation is very slightly. Change `yRotated += 0.01;` to `yRotated += 1.0;`, for debug reasons (the angle is specified in degrees).

[image]

Comment: I've made those modifications, and they are now rotating on their individual axis.  

How do I get them to move in unison from one side of the screen to the other?  Any changes I've made to the idle function seem to be having no effect.

Comment: Ahhhh!  I just figured it out!